# GCP logs show function "Function execution took xxx ms. Finished with status: response error" whenever my header status code is not 200

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

As stated in the title, whenever I set my response header to be any status code besides the default (200), I receive a response error in my logs. This did not happen a few weeks ago so I am not sure why it is happening now. Another thread:  [Firebase Cloud Function finished with status: 'response error'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68865573/firebase-cloud-function-finished-with-status-response-error)
said that the HTTP request of response of my function is higher than 10MB. However, I decided to just deploy a function (getTest) that is just

```
package foo

import (
    "net/http"
)

func GetTest(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Status Code Test
    w.WriteHeader(201) // Testing with status code 201
    return
}
```

and I am still returned a 'response error'. Replacing any status code (201,400,404,500,etc.) for 200 in the above test code would result in a successful GCP log of status code 200.

Furthermore, GCP would **sometimes** automatically invoke the function again with a status 200 if the previous invocation ended in a response error as shown in photo #1. I say sometimes because I cannot consistently exhibit the issue. It is to my belief that during this re-invocation nothing in my code is actually executed and it just returns a 200.

Does anyone know the issue?

Edit: I also want to point out I only see this "response error" on Cloud Function Logs. On my API gateway logs, I see the correct status code the function ended on.

[image: Photo #1]

Comment: Can you share the exact code that you are using to run GCP functions? I would like to test it and check if I have the same issue.

Comment: Hello Priyashree Bhadra, the code for my getTest cloud function is posted above. That is what I deployed to my gcp environment. Are you asking if you would like to see my other functions? If so, I cannot easily share them for security reasons. However, if someone provides a suitable justification as to why they would need to see the code for my other cloud functions, I will spend the effort to share as much as I can.

Comment: The product team is aware of this issue and they have updated today that the change is reverted back, you can expect the previous behavior to be resumed shortly.   Let me know if you face any errors after a day or two.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra, any news on this? Do you have a trouble report ID or somehow to track this? I'm seeing this very frequently in my logs as well..

Comment: @GiggleGrass, I am so, SO, happy that you wrote this. I'm observing what seems to be the exact same behavior. I got so freakin scared when I saw that mysterious extra invocation of the function, which resulted in a 200. In my case it could have indicated that it triggered an extra debit for my customer.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra Hello, unfortunately, I am still receiving the "response error" log even after updating the gcloud CLI version from v381 to v382.

Comment: @GiggleGrass The product team is working on the rollout. We have reports of these issues, it has been completed in us-central1 region. Hopefully users in other regions can expect the rest of the rollout to complete by end of this week. If your function is in us-central1 and still the issue is not fixed, I would suggest lets wait for the rollout to end for other regions and then check. Be assured this is at priority. For any more queries, you can contact Google Support at [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0]

Comment: Any update on this? I am seeing this error constantly on us-central1

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra What is the ETA for the rollout to end for the other regions? Thanks

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra do we need to do anything to get rid of this situation? Currently, we are getting this error (second call) for every function invocation. 

`Function execution took xx ms. Finished with status: response error `

Comment: Google has recently made several updaets on Firebase. Is it possible that they are the cause of these things? I've had the same problems for the last few days, but when I try to reproduce them, the functions work for me, but some clients get this error... It is really annoying

Comment: The roll out is in progress to production. The latest update says we should expect changes by the end of the week.

Comment: Is there an issue on the tracker that we can follow for status updates on this problem? It is past the end of the week and the issue is still unresolved in us-central1.

Comment: The roll out has finished. Please check and let me know if its fine now.

Comment: So far it looks good! Thank you for the update Priyashree Bhadra!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE :**

GCP Functions were receiving a response error in the logs `Function execution took xxx ms. Finished with status: response error` for quite some time whenever the  header status code was not set to 200. This was an internal issue with Google which got fixed with the roll out on 17th May 2022. You can expect Cloud functions to work in the expected manner now. If you have any further queries or if it is still an issue with you, you can contact Google Support at [issuetracker.google.com/issues/…](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=0%5D) or raise a support case.